# Japanese thick old book

Tags: discussion

[image]I am looking to find out something about this book. I have no idea about it's age. Seems pretty old. This page is the first page of the book. It has a few colored illustrations and a few black and white ones to of people and landscapers. It is about 4"x7" and 4 inches thick. Anything you can tell about it would be great. If you need more pictures let me know. It would be a great help if you could translate this page. Thanks Kirk

Answer (score 1):

Hokkaido university library shows [the book](http://base1.nijl.ac.jp/iview/Frame.jsp?DB_ID=G0003917KTM&C_CODE=HOKU-00098&IMG_SIZE=&PROC_TYPE=null&SHOMEI=%E3%80%90%E6%AD%8C%E6%9B%B2%E6%99%82%E7%BF%92%E8%80%83%E3%80%91&REQUEST_MARK=null&OWNER=null&BID=null&IMG_NO=7) on the Internet. (See page 7 in the link)

[Kakyoku Sarae Kou](https://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=779668&partId=1) published in 1805 (文化2年).
Your picture version is 「嘉永新鐫(か えい しん せん)」. This might augumented in 1848 (嘉永元年).

There are many 地歌(じか)'s song lyrics over 400 songs.
地歌 is traditional song in Japan.
This is chanted on the samisen in Kyoto, Osaka and the outskirts.